# How to add entries to database using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add entries to my database from HTML forms in my view, but I am not sure if my code is a good practice. I really struggled with the matching properties but I am not sure how did I done this.

This is my code:

Controller:

```
cinereservacionEntities CineBD = new cinereservacionEntities();

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Peliculas_Agregar(PeliculasVM pelis) 
{
    using (var context = new cinereservacionEntities()) 
    {
        var s  = context.peliculas.Add(new pelicula() 
                                           {
                                               id_peli = pelis.Id_peli,
                                               titulo = pelis.Titulo,
                                               director = pelis.Director,
                                               cast = pelis.Cast, 
                                               descripcion = pelis.Descripcion,
                                               categoria = pelis.Categoria
                                           });

        CineBD.peliculas.Add(s);
        CineBD.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(pelis);
}
```

My code worked and entries worked but I am asking if my code is well-programmed or there is another solution/practice to simplify the entry.

Comment: I don't think SO is the right place to ask such questions. Try [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's a matter of opinion really. One person's best practice is another person's heresy. Personally in these situations I find it can be beneficial to use a tool like AutoMapper to map between the viewmodel and database fields. It can save tedious coding and result in less maintenance when you add or remove fields from the model. Also you really ought to be checking if the modelstate is valid before you attempt the insert.

Comment: But the main thing I'd say is: why have you got two database context objects? `CineBD` should not be needed. Replace `CineBD.peliculas.Add(s);
        CineBD.SaveChanges();` with just `context.SaveChanges();` and then you can also remove `cinereservacionEntities CineBD = new cinereservacionEntities();`. I don't know if you got confused with that or what, but it makes no sense to add the record to one context, but then transfer it to another.

Comment: This is the one way of doing it but best practice is by following view model as @ADyson mentioned. You can do all your validations, mappings everything in there itself and you dont need about maintenance in future. Always think how in case of adding or removing new things down the line. So that you will not end up in bad architecture.